# Compiler for ConEMU

Tags: c++, compilation, conemu

I just downloaded ConEMU and I'm starting to explore some of the options on my own. I can't seem to find a start-up tutorial anywhere, or a list of awesome features, or anything like that so that's what I'm here for.

More specifically, the one main feature I'm trying to get out of ConEMU is a built-in compiler somehow (if this is possible).

I know that Mac terminals have the ability to type "g++ ..." to compile C++ code, and I want my terminal to have the same capabilities.

Other than that, I am looking for a list of awesome features, shortcuts, hotkeys, or anything of that sort.

Thanks a lot

Comment: So you really have two questions: 1) how to get a command line compiler tool chain installed on your machine (this really has nothing to do with ConEMU), and 2) what are some of the awesome features, etc., of ConEMU?

Comment: @MichaelBurr Yes, that's what I was asking. I didn't realize ConEMU didn't have that support

Comment: Mac terminals don't "come with support" for g++, either.  Neither do DOS prompts, or *nix command lines.  You need to install the compiler on the *operating system*.  The "shell" that executes in the "terminal window" merely executes commands available from the OS.

Comment: http://conemu.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

"conemu" gives you nothing to "compile a program".

SUGGESTION:

It sounds like you're on Windows.

If so, consider trying MinGW: http://www.mingw.org/

You might also like CodeBlocks + Gcc (with C++11 support): http://www.codeblocks.org/